# How to make a new android activity launch a specific action from the old activity?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to modify the android version of the Xamarin MediaPlugin (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) to my needs so that when the `MediaPickerActivity` is accidentally canceled by the user (for example by pressing the hardware back button while the device is importing images from the gallery) it also cancels the whole import task.

For that reason my main activity needs to pass a `CancellationTokenSource` (or an action that invokes the cancellation) to the new `MediaPickerActivity`.

But I dont know how to implement that since one can only pass simple data types to a new activity via `PutExtra` on the new intent.

This is the function which I am waiting for in my Xamarin project:

```cs
public async Task<List<MediaFile>> PickPhotosAsync(PickMediaOptions options = null, MultiPickerOptions pickerOptions = null, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
{
  ...
}
```

So I'm passing a `CancellationToken` from my `CancellationTokenSource`.

This function now starts a new activity and I want that `OnBackPressed` (in this new activity) itself cancels the whole task with the `CancellationTokenSource`.

Comment: Is your "import task" running in a `Service` or at the `Application` level of the app?

Comment: Application level

Comment: Expose a public cancel method from within your application subclass and call it from that second activity when needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the problem is I don't know how to reference the original object from the new activity.

Comment: What original object? If your import task is running at the app level, you can obtain a reference to the application singleton object via the application context and reference any public members (same as it sounds like you are doing when you start the application level task from the first activity).

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm relatively new to this android specific stuff. I read a couple of articles about contexts but it's still not clear to me.
Let's make it specifc:
In the class ```MediaImplementation``` there is the base function ```PickPhotosAsync``` which takes the ```CancellationToken``` as an argument.
This function starts the new activity with ```Application.context```.
So how do I access a specific public method in the ```MediaImplementation``` class from the new activity using the context?